# Reading From One Child Process Blocks Other Children

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, fork, file-descriptor

As you can see from the code I shared below, I am trying to implement 1 central server and `n` children. First I create all `n` children by forking from the server. Also, before forking I create bidirectional pipes using `Pipe`. Having forked and created `n` children, I want to read characters from child codes. They all send character 'A', but I can only read from one child. I use poll to select active children and try to read data from them. What may cause the program to block on one child? I will appreciate any help.

```
#define Pipe(fd) socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, PF_UNIX, fd)
int n = 5;    
struct pollfd pfd[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    Pipe(fd[i]);
    if (fork() == 0){
        close(fd[i][0]);
        dup2(fd[i][1], 0);
        dup2(fd[i][1], 1);
        close(fd[i][1]);
        execl(code, arguments);
    }

    else {
        close(fd[i][1]);
        dup2(fd[i][0], 0);
        dup2(fd[i][0], 1);
        close(fd[i][0]);
    }

    struct pollfd s;
    s.fd = fd[i][1];
    s.events = POLLIN;
    s.revents = 0;
    pfd[i] = s;
}   

while(1){
    poll(pfd, n, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (pfd[i].revents && POLLIN){
            char data;
            read(0, &data, 1);

            if (data == 'A'){ 
            .
            .
            .
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one standard input file descriptor and one standard output file descriptor in the parent.  Your code is like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    Pipe(fd[i]);
    if (fork() == 0){
        close(fd[i][0]);
        dup2(fd[i][1], 0);
        dup2(fd[i][1], 1);
        close(fd[i][1]);
        execv(code, arguments);
    }
    else {
        close(fd[i][1]);
        dup2(fd[i][0], 0);
        dup2(fd[i][0], 1);
        close(fd[i][0]);
    }
    …poll setup…
}
```

This carefully zaps standard input and standard output in the parent every time a child is created, leaving the program with only the connection to the last child.

You should not be using `dup2()` like that in the parent; you probably need to keep the file descriptors open in the array so that you use them to communicate with the children separately.

I have not reviewed why you're using subscripts `[0]` and `[1]` after `fd[i]` as you are, but it doesn't feel right.

You should put at minimum an `exit(1);` or `_exit(1);` after the `execv()` call; I'd prefer to see an error message printed to `stderr` too, reporting that the `execv()` failed.  You don't need to check the return value; if `execv()` returns, it failed; if it succeeds, it does not return.  Otherwise, if the `execv()` fails, you can end up with multiple processes all thinking they're the parent.  That leads to chaos.  Always ensure you handle failure to execute other programs!

Comment: You are absolutely right! I should keep file descriptors of the parent open to communicate with `n` children.